# Kubuntu, Flex mode ram and intel graphics

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, ram

I'm running Kubuntu 15.10 and I have a Gigabyte GA-G41M-Combo.
I'm using the integrated Intel graphics.
I'm trying to use a 4Gb ram stick and a 2Gb (different speeds). Both memories work fine by themselves. Since the mb supports flex mode I went ahead and tried it.
The computer boots fine, and Windows XP (which is on an older disk in dual-boot) also works fine.
In Kubuntu I'm having graphics issues. Plasmois, panels and kicker work as they should, but the rest isn't rendering well.
Is there a way to get graphics to work with "flex mode" ram?

Answer (score 0):

I found (reading through the internet) the issue is the graphics card that doesn't support flex mode (it's just weird because it's integrated in a mb that does support it).